# Siesta Swift: RequestError.Cause.RequestCancelled not conform to _ErrorCodeProtocol

Tags: siesta-swift

I'm trying to check what exact error a request might throw by doing some custom checks and throw my own custom errors.

```
if let cause = resource.latestError?.cause {
    if case RequestError.Cause.RequestCancelled = cause {

    }
}
```

I get this error:

> Argument type 'RequestError.Cause.RequestCancelled.Type' does not conform to expected type '_ErrorCodeProtocol'

Any ideas how I could check what the exact cause of the error is and then return my own custom errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Siesta’s error causes are open to extension and thus **not an enum**, so the `if case` syntax doesn’t work with them. (The compiler error you’re getting is because Swift thinks you’re trying to use `case` to extract an error code from an error that doesn’t have one.)

Siesta’s error causes are instead a tree of distinct types. Instead of using `if case`, match error causes using `is`:

```
if let cause = resource.latestError?.cause {
  if cause is RequestError.Cause.RequestCancelled {

  }
}
```

…or simply:

```
if resource.latestError?.cause is RequestError.Cause.RequestCancelled {

}
```

…or if you need to assign the type-narrowed error to a variable so you can do something further with it:

```
if let cause = resource.latestError?.cause as? RequestError.Cause.RequestCancelled {

}
```

Comment: Thanks! That helps a lot. How would I be able to differentiate between a "RequestCancelled" and a "Network Error"? Considering networkError is a member of RequestCancelled, how can I check for one or the other as they both represent two different types of errors.

Comment: I think you’re confused; the code above does what you’re asking for. RequestCancelled _has a_ network error, not _is a_ network error. The code above will only match cancellations. The [error types defined by Siesta](https://bustoutsolutions.github.io/siesta/api/Structs/RequestError/Cause.html) are only for errors Siesta itself detects; if the underlying networking layer reports an error, then Siesta just passes that error straight through in the `cause`.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you for a well written explanation.